# the MediaContentType{n} start from 0 or 1?

Tags: twilio

When twilio sends a  request for an incoming message with mediacontents inside,  the NumMedia parameter value is the number of  related MediaContentTypes.
Are they numbered from 0 to (NumMedia -1) or from 1 to NumMedia?

Answer (score 0):

They are number as MediaContentType0 to MediaContentType9 and MediaUrl0 to MedialUrl9